# Android fork child process

Tags: android, fork, dalvik

I was wondering if someone could answer a question about Android dalvik for me. If I were to fork a child process from my application, would both processes share a single instance of the Dalvik VM? I remember reading somewhere(I couldn't find the link) that only applications with different application signatures would have different instances of the Dalvik. I'm assuming the forked process would have the same application signatures as the parent process since they are the same application. I would appreciate it if someone could clarify this for me.

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you've got your answer below, but let me throw in one other bit: don't use `fork()` in an Android app unless you're planning to follow it with an `exec()`.  The `fork()` system call only clones the current thread.  The Android zygote works by shutting down all but one thread, creating the new process, then starting (or re-starting) the various VM threads.

Comment: Thank you for the tip! I've actually got another question regarding the android dalvik. Would you mind trying to look at it? The link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17475062/stress-testing-android-dalvik